# DFP ads not showing on ajaxified website

Tags: wordpress, google-dfp, ajaxify

I used the Browser State/ajaxify gist (https://github.com/browserstate) on a Wordpress-based website to dynamically load content. The problem I'm running into is that now my Google DFP ads aren't loading when the content is dynamically loaded.

The ads worked normally before, so I'm not sure exactly what the issue is. Am I overlooking something simple, or are there extra steps that need to be taken?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the javascript that load ads from dfp read your page when it's ready. But with your ajax loading mechanism, you never inform this javascript that it need to re-read the page and load newly inserted tags.

So you have to catch the new content insertion event and fire the loading method that the dfp javascript provide.